# How to map complexed xml file data in aws glue?

Tags: python, aws-glue

Is there any way through which we can map below mentioned data in aws glue.The task is to migrate xml file into database using aws glue but i am not able to transform this type of data correctly .So if anyone can help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

struct < array: array < struct < FirstName:string ,
LastName:string > >, struct : struct < FirstName:string,LastName:string> >

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: the issue is how to migrate xml file when it contains nested tags! like the format of my file is <tag><nestedtag>abcd</nestedtag><nestedtag1>efgh</nestedtag1></tag> i am not able to do any transformation in this type of tags

Answer (score 0):

AWS Glue documents explain XML input format.
You can load XML files as dataframe.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-format.html
https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml

Comment: i have gone through this link but didn't get any kind of help from it